# Entity access based on owner user

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a Spring MVC webapp using also spring security.

Based on the  logged user and the currently accessed Entity  I have to permit or deny the user to view  or modify it. If the user has created the Entity, he is the owner and he can handle the entity. I can verify it because entity.user == user.

I have also situations in which the user can be compared only by getting the parent of a entity, or the n-parent. for Example entity.nestedEntity.user == user

I've seen that spring security have ACL support (domain object security), but I think that I cannot handle the "parent scenario". And I'm not starting with an empty db. Additionally I think I need to build the acl for each object.. so I think it is not the proper way.

By now I do the check in controller layer, getting the current user and comparing it with the user stored in the requested object. If they are not same I throw an AccessDeniedException.

What alternative approaches can I take in order to keep things as simple as possible?

Thank you Marco

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement your own PermissionEvaluator that will check your custom permission logic.
Then you register your newly created PermissionEvaluator with Spring Security and you can use
you your custom permission checks in Spring Security annotations.

Minimal example (spring security config):

```
<!-- Enable usage of @Pre & @Post security annotations -->
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"  pre-post-annotations="enabled">
      <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>

<!-- Use CustomPermissionEvaluator as permission evaluator to control access to    application with specific permission rules -->
<beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
     <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="customPermissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customPermissionEvaluator" class="com.example.CustomPermissionEvaluator">
```

and then your CustomPermissionEvalutor should have hasPermission implementation that does permission checking for your custom "OWNER" permission and your custom domain object.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
    ...
    if ("OWNER".equals(permission.toString()) && targetDomainObject instanceof Entity) {
         //fetch user from Authentication and verify if user is owner of Entity
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, you'll be able to enforce security with annotations:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#someEntity, 'OWNER')")
public someMethod(Entity someEntity) { ... }
```

It is also possible (but more complicated) to add new functions you can evaluate in Spring Security annotations, in that case, you could add your own isOwner function and PreAuthorize could look like @PreAuthorize('isOwner(#someEntity)') etc...

Comment: mmm I like it! I will give it a try!